# appcelerator Android tableview crashes on setData SDK6

Tags: android, tableview, appcelerator

I have a tableview in a View XML and it crashes when I set the data via setData on SK6. Works fine on SDK 5, but on SDK6 it crashes when I assign the same data twice which I do when I need to switch data sets. This is only on Android as iOS works as it should

```
$table.setData(myDataSet);
$table.data = [];
$table.setData(newDataSet);   // This is ok
$table.data = [];
$table.setData(myDataSet);    // Re-assigning myDataSet crashes the table view
```

I am guessing this is a bug in SDK6 forAndroid - anyone else had the same issue?

Thanks

Nigel

Comment: Provide more info about the structure of **myDataSet** & **newDataSet**. Something is wrong with your data-set. Also change **$table** to **$.table** if it was not a typo error.

Comment: That was a typo for $ and should have been $.table. The datasets are TI views and this is working fine on SDK5 for android and iOS, but only SDK 6 for iOS. I get the crashing on SDK 6 for android only. I've done some further testing and it only crashes if the SAME dataset is assigned twice, I can keep adding new datasets and it won't crash, but assign the same again and it crashes.

Comment: You can file a bug at JIRA if you thinks it only having issues in SDK 6+.

Comment: Just done that as I pretty sure this is an SDK6 issue since its fine on SDK5

Comment: Please provide the error that you receive after crash.